# Creating a data-table from input text

Tags: jquery

I got a question about JQuery. I got previously this code http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/8/
It works quite well but it creates input fields. I would like to have the inputted data to get stored under a table below ( with some fade add delay with green background ). I know it isn't hard to edit the current code but im really not that good in JQ. Looking forward you'r tips.

Thanks !

```
http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/4936/btlo.png
```

Comment: `looking forward to tips`....more like `can't wait for you to code this for me`. You need to make an attempt, and post your code attempts outling where you have problems

Comment: As you see I got a part of the code I have no idea how to put them into the table below:\

Comment: look...demo code doesn't do anyhting in UI. Start other way around...create html structure you want and then add script to make it do what you want. As it stands right now...we have no idea what your code is supposed to do

Comment: each time u fill the input with 24 numbers it supposed to create a <span> for example with the value of the input, i will try to do it in html and leave it unscripted

Comment: that would likely be best place to start... code shown in demo is a lot more code than needed to do what you just described, can be done in in about 6-8 lines given html to work with